# I can't run the forms which I'm building

Tags: oracle11g

I have a problem with my 11g Oracle: I can't run the forms which I'm building
- I'm getting this pop-up:

[image: a pop-up]

> FRM-10142: The HTTP Listener is not running on
>   Mohamed-PC at port 7001 . Please start the listener or
>   check your runtime preferences.

- then I tried to run the listener and I found that already running:

> ```
> C:\Users\Mohamed>lsnrctl start
> LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 27-Mar-2018 22:13
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle. All rights reserved.
> TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started
> C:\Users\Mohamed>
> ```

and I used the *reset default* option in *forms edit* menu - in the Runtime tab:

[image]

Only `Array Processing` is checked, `Application Server URL` is set to `http://Mohamed-PC:7001` and `Web Browser Location` to `C:\Program Files\Mozilla F…`.

Comment: (I find `iam` much harder to read than *I'm* (use a spelling checker).) Please include the error message in your question as a *block quote*. Do not present (program) text as a heap of pixels.

Comment: sorry till now i cant post images because i haven't 10 reputation..i am a new oracle and stackoverflow user...but i put the links of the images.

Answer (score 0):

Solved...i removed every thing related with oracle 11g and setup new windows this installed 11g again... ( i think the problem was in weblogic configration).